# Magento2 slow checkout

Tags: magento2

**How to optimize checkout speed.**

> It's take to much time to load data.
>
> Loader take almost 60 secs
>
> It's almost heating 560 js request in my site

Comment: Merge js and css files. Enable cache.

Comment: already done but still taking time

Comment: Also, I would suggest, please remove unwanted script, so it will optimize and load fast. Still, it will not work properly, then you need to debug using the profiler tool.

Comment: Yes i have checked using profiler but checkout contecnt load using ajax and profiler that time is not counting